# как преобразовать значения в гиперссылки

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как то,что на картинке превратить в нормальные ги[image: введите сюда описание изображения]перссылки

```
 let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(dataObject);
    let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
    dataObject.forEach(item => {
      let div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerText = "<a href='"+item+"'></a>" ;
      div.classList.add("div-added");
      menu.append(div);
    });
```

Comment: Что значит нормальные?

Comment: нормальные значит вместо a href ='food' просто подчеркнутое слово  food

Answer (score 1):

```js
let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
dataObject.forEach(item => {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  let a = document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href", "/" + item);
  a.innerText = item;
  div.appendChild(a);
  div.classList.add("div-added");
  menu.append(div);
});

//второй вариант
let dataObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
let menu = document.getElementById('menu');
dataObject.forEach(item => {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "<a href='/" + item + "'>'" + item + "'</a>"; // не innerText
  div.classList.add("div-added");
  menu.append(div);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Не используйте `innerText`, здесь нужен `innerHTML`, он позволит вставлять html код. Также вы не добавили текст для ссылки, используйте  например так: `div.innerHTML = "<a href='"+item+"'>" + item +"</a>"`;